# Can't find the Unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Normally the T_String error is when there is an extra quote, or atleast I thought. Tonight I got this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/registerBackend.php on line 118
```

and here is the code for line 118+119

```
$query = "INSERT INTO User (Name,Email,Password,Port) VALUES ('$name', '$email','$password','$port')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

Here is some more code if it helps

```
 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

 $dbname ='hidden';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Check if Username has been used before
$query = "SELECT * FROM User where Name='$name'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$countName=mysql_num_rows($result);

//Check if email has been used before
$query = "SELECT * FROM User where Email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$countEmail=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($countName < 1 && $countEmail < 1){

//Assign their port number
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login;
$countPort=mysql_num_rows($result);
$port = 20000 + $countPort;


$query = "INSERT INTO User (Name,Email,Password,Port) VALUES ('$name', '$email','$password','$port')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');


$query  = "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

print "<center><div id=newAREA>You have been signed up!<br>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  echo "Minecraft Username:{$row['Name']} <br>" .
       "Email:{$row['Email']} <br>" .
       "Password:{$row['Password']} <br>".
       "Port:{$row['Port']} <br>";

}
} elseif ($countName > 1) {
print "Someone has already used this Minecraft IGN! E-mail Stolen@freeminecrafthost.com   to prove it is yours!";
} elseif ($countEmail > 1) {
print "Email has been used before!";
}
```

Comment: Do you have a quote in any of those variables?

Comment: Check the files before it and make sure you're not missing a quote.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Paste a few lines before that, too. You could have forgotten a semicolon above that line.

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: @SLaks, in the scope of this post's defense, you don't know what `$password` contains.

Comment: What's on line 117?  That's likely where your error is.

Comment: @Blake -- obviously something to cause the error; and it could be in any of those fields. Yikes, OP needs some input validation.

Comment: I pasted the code around it, and @Slaks I plan on adding the mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($var)); to all the values, will that protect me form mySQL injection?

Comment: You have a race condition with IDs.

Comment: @JeremySayers, you don't need `stripslashes()`, but `mysql_real_escape_string()` will work as a poor man's band aid for now.

Comment: @stealthynija I do have input validation, and when I tested the form I entered in all valid data, no quotes at all in any of the feilds

Comment: @JeremySayers -- that means the problem is occurring above where PHP is reporting it to be. Check that every line has a semi-colon (`;`) after it.

Comment: @JeremySayers, I already gave you the answer. Escaping your variables isn't causing the error (though important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line:

```
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login;
```

you need to have:

```
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login";
```

But definitely need to give those queries some lovin, too.

Comment: Thank you so much Blake! That was exactly the problem!

Comment: What editor do you use? Code highlighting can save lots of headaches. I, personally, enjoy [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org).

Comment: and don't forget to mark something as the answer if provided (Up votes are helpful as well) :]

Comment: Dont worry :) I remembered it just made me wait 2 mins until I could lol Now one last thing, it puts all the values into the DB perfectly but give this error Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /var/www/html/registerBackend.php on line 127

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$query = "INSERT INTO User (Name,Email,Password,Port) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($port) . "')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

**Update**

This line

```
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login;
```

should be

```
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login";
```

Comment: Still getting the same error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/registerBackend.php on line 118, But thanks for the help with the injection protection :D

Comment: @JeremySayers -- Updated my answer after your update.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Assign their port number
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login;
$countPort=mysql_num_rows($result);
$port = 20000 + $countPort;
```

You're missing a quote after `login`.

```
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM login";
```

Praise be, syntax highlighting!